# How do I have two different locations for text (Top & Bottom) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to figure out how I can have text at the bottom left of my custom card component and also have text at the top left to act as the title

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is here:
[image: card design]

Right now I have a custom Card component as shown below:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 8, 10, 8),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 8, 10, 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And then I am using this card component like so:

```
  return CustomCard(
    colour: Color(0xFF303030),
    cardChild: Column(
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "Top Text",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28)
        ),
        Text(
          "Bottom Text",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

I think what I could do is have a container for the bottom left text, it got me close to the result but I don't think I was doing it quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `Expanded(child: SizedBox())` Widget between both `Text` Widgets

```
return CustomCard(
  colour: Color(0xFF303030),
  cardChild: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text("Top Text", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28)),
      Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
      Text("Bottom Text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18))
    ],
  ),
);
```

If you want, you can add a `Padding` Widget wrapping your `Column` to add internal padding to your `Card` Widget.

Comment: Would this allow to move the bottom text alignment to the right? It does work with moving the text to the bottom (thanks!), although just for future reference, how could I move the bottom text to the right too if I wanted to?

Comment: you can wrap your bottom text into a Contrainer or Align Widget and changes its alignment to bottom right if you want... or any alignment.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is to add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to the `Column`:

https://www.dartpad.dev/fb357b9308db33ce11074a9c5f7aa41e?null_safety=true